# How to take Permissions to retrive uploadimage through url in S3bucket

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-s3

I successfully uploaded an image to an S3 bucket and my requirement is to display that uploaded image through a URL in my UIImageview.

When I am browsing that URL the image is displaying but when I am using that URL in the following code, the URL is printing in the console. When converting that URL in to data it contains nil value.

I tried the following code. Can any one tell me if the problem is the permissions in the S3 bucket or coding?

```
let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl)
let responseData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!,options: nil,error:nil)
print("The data is \(responseData)")
changeImgVC.image = UIImage(data:responseDataenter!)
```

Comment: paste your url in browser where you are not logged in to s3 Bucket. Can you see the image?

Comment: yes when I am pasting that url in browser image is displaying

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place upload image in AWSS3bucket to UIImageview in XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821173/how-to-place-upload-image-in-awss3bucket-to-uiimageview-in-xcode)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the policy of your bucket in the AWS S3 console:
- http://www.jppinto.com/2011/12/access-denied-to-file-amazon-s3-bucket/
- http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html
- Add to Bucket>Properties>Permissions>Bucket Policy

Answer (score 0):

Check that your permissions on your server allow people to view the file. It is returning "nil" because the server is not granting access to the file.

I just set a permission of "everyone" to allow "Open/Download".

I tried this code im my project with my s3 account, after I changed the permission for the image file it worked.

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/YOUR_BUCKET/SOME_IMAGE_FROM_SERVER.png")!
    let responseData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url,options: nil,error:nil)
    print("The data is \(responseData)")

    var changeImgVC = UIImageView()
    changeImgVC.image = UIImage(data: responseData!)
    self.view.addSubview(changeImgVC)
```